# Send Summary SOAP API returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm using Postman to test my API skills in Marketing Cloud. I created the following SOAP API to pull some details on a specific Send.

FYI, the endpoint is : `https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx;`

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">     
<Header>
        <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>  
</Header>   
<Body>      
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
<RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>SendSummary</ObjectType>
                    <Properties>AccountEmail</Properties>
                    <Properties>AccountID</Properties>
                    <Properties>AccountName</Properties>
                    <Properties>Client</Properties>
                    <Properties>SendID</Properties>
                <filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <value>692734</value>
                </filter> 
</RetrieveRequest>      
</RetrieveRequestMsg>   
</Body> 
</Envelope>
```

Can someone please tell me why the response is coming out :

> WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following
>   information is missing: action.

Answer (score 1):

Note the action in the header.  Also note the To node in the header -- update with your stack, ie s7, s8, swhatever.  Alternatively, if you are using OAuth 2.0 for the installed package retrieving the Token, you may need https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx in the To node of the Header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.{{yourstack}}.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
     <a:fueloauth><![CDATA[{{accessToken}}]]></a:fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>SendSummary</ObjectType>
            <Properties>AccountEmail</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountID</Properties>
            <Properties>AccountName</Properties>
            <Properties>Client</Properties>
            <Properties>SendID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>ID</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <value>692734</value>
            </Filter> 
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Updated with a full request example.

Comment: I tried that - it still gives me the same error

Comment: @balwill I have updated the request to include all the nodes I typically include in my Postman request body.

Comment: I tried above out of curiosity and was also getting "information is missing: action." for the original envelope with Action added in the header. For your updated version of the answer, I am just getting a 400 Bad request (of course with modified filter, stack and token)